# Test if std::common_type exists

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I want to write a helper template that checks if a template parameter pack has a common type, i.e., if applying `std::common_type` to the pack defines a type.

Using [std::void_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) with SFINAE I came up with the following definition:

```
template<typename... Types, typename Enable = void>
struct has_common_type : std::false_type
{ };

template<typename... Types>
struct has_common_type<Types..., std::void_t<std::common_type<Types...>::type>> : std::true_type
{ };
```

This however does not work, because the template parameter pack must be the last parameter. The compiler raises the following error:

```
error: template parameter pack must be the last template parameter
                        template<typename... Types, typename Enable = void>
```

How can one go about defining such a template?

Comment: For something decently likely to be standardized soon, you could copy the small implementation of [`is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected). Then all you need is a `template<typename... Types> using has_common_type_test = std::common_type<Types...>;` for use in the `is_detected` "call". It uses `void_t`, but not directly like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Option #1

```
template <typename... Ts>
using has_common_type = std::experimental::is_detected<std::common_type_t, Ts...>;
```

[**DEMO**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/zJkbcLqmzLH0mBt5)

---

#### Option #2

```
template <typename AlwaysVoid, typename... Ts>
struct has_common_type_impl : std::false_type {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct has_common_type_impl<std::void_t<std::common_type_t<Ts...>>, Ts...> : std::true_type {};

template <typename... Ts>
using has_common_type = typename has_common_type_impl<void, Ts...>::type;
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Iorm3Sa7DncPo8pJ)

Comment: I guess, the last line of Option #2 should be: `template <typename... Ts>
constexpr bool has_common_type_v = has_common_type_impl<void, Ts...>::value;`