# Is there a way to define a variadic number of arguments of the same type?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I can't figure out how to implement a function with a variable number of arguments of the same type.

I'm writing for a microcontroller with little stack and memory, so I can't use recursion or the STL (the parts with exceptions).

Is it possible to make such a function?

```
struct S{
int r1;
int r2;
};
template<S* s, int... args> fun(int arg1, int arg2);
```

which expands to something like this:

```
for(int arg:args){ 
s->r1+=7*arg;
}
```

example of invocation:

```
S s;
const int mode=3, speed=1;

fun<&s,1,2,7,4>(mode,speed);
```

Comment: `int... args` is correct.  Do you have actual code that uses it that isn't working?

Comment: @logicstuff It's been around since C++11.  You can have a pack of types or values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to implement a function with a variable number of arguments of the same type.

Template argument of the same type or ordinary function arguments of the same type?

The first case is simple (if the type is one admitted for template value types), exactly as you have written

```
template<S* s, int... args>
fun (int arg1, int arg2);
```

and you can use they using template folding, if you can use C++17,

```
template <S* s, int... args>
auto fun (int arg1, int arg2)
 { ((s->r1 += 7 * args), ...); }
```

or in a little more complicated way before (C++11/C++14)

```
template <S* s, int... args>
auto fun (int arg1, int arg2)
 { 
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0, s->r1 += 7 * args ... };
 }
```

Unfortunately you can call this type of function with compile time known integers so, by example, not with variables

```
int a = 7;
fun<&s,1,2,a,4>(mode,speed); // compilation error
```

In this case you need a variadic list of ordinary function arguments of the same type; unfortunately  this is a little more complicated.

You can create a typical variadic list of template parameter

```
template <typename ... Args>
auto fun (Args ... args)
```

imposing, through SFINAE, that all `Args...` are deduced or explicated as `int` (see Michael Kenzel's answer).

Unfortunately this require that every argument is exactly if type `int` so calling func with (by example) a `long int` gives a compilation error

```
fun(1, 2, 3l); // compilation error (3l is a long int, not an int)
```

Obviously you can relax the SFINAE condition imposing (by example) that all `Args...` types are convertible (`std::is_convertible`) to `int` but isn't exactly has developing a function receiving a variadic number of arguments of the same type.

If you can accept a superior limit to the number of arguments (`64`, in the following example) and that the function is method (maybe static) of a class, you can create a `foo` class containing a method `f()` that receive zero `int`, one `f()` that receive one `int`, one `f()` that receive two `int`s, etc, until an `f()` that receive 63 `int`s.

The following is a full compiling C++17 example

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

struct S
{
    int r1;
    int r2;
};

S s;
const int mode=3, speed=1;

template <typename T, std::size_t>
using getType = T;

template <std::size_t N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct bar;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct bar<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 {
   static constexpr auto f (getType<int, Is> ... args)
    { ((s.r1 += 7 * args), ...); }
 };

template <S &, std::size_t N = 64u, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct foo;

template <S & s, std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct foo<s, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> : public bar<Is>...
 { using bar<Is>::f...; };

int main ()
 {
   foo<s>::f(mode, speed);
 }
```

In C++14 is a little more complicated because there isn't variadic `using` so you have to write the `foo` class in a recursive way.

In C++11 you have also to develop a substitute for `std::make_index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence`.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this with **fold expression** (c++17) and **concepts** (c++20) features.

The concept will look like this:

```
template<typename T, typename... Types>
concept is_all_same = (... && std::is_same<T, Types>::value);
```

If you want them to be just the same type, you can use it this way:

```
template<typename... Types> requires is_all_same<Types...>
void fun();
```

If you want a function to take a specific type, you can use it this way:

```
template<is_all_same<int>... Types>
void fun();
```

Answer (score 2):

Having all parameters in a variadic pack be of same type can be ***required*** with C++20 concepts.

Unfortunately, as of C++20, [the standard library doesn't have a concept for *all_same*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts) (there is only `std::same_as` for two types), but it can be easily defined:

```
template<class... Ts>
concept all_same = 
        sizeof...(Ts) < 2 ||
        std::conjunction_v<
            std::is_same<std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Ts...>>, Ts>...
        >;

template<typename... Ts> requires all_same<Ts...>
void foo(Ts&&... ts) {}
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/dH9t-N

---

**Note** that in many cases requiring same type is not necessary, you may instead require that all arguments have a ***common type***. To require common type, based on *[test if common type exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748199/test-if-stdcommon-type-exists)* you can have the following concept:

```
template <typename AlwaysVoid, typename... Ts>
struct has_common_type_impl : std::false_type {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct has_common_type_impl<std::void_t<std::common_type_t<Ts...>>, Ts...>
    : std::true_type {};

template <typename... Ts>
concept has_common_type = 
    sizeof...(Ts) < 2 ||
    has_common_type_impl<void, Ts...>::value;

template<typename... Ts> requires has_common_type<Ts...>
void foo(Ts&&... ts) {}
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/5M6dLp

Comment: tuple stuff is simply : template<class T, class ... Ts>
struct head {
    using type = T;
};

Comment: a _t version of head : template<typename ... Ts>
using head_t = typename head<Ts...>::type;

Comment: giving : template<class ... Ts>
concept all_same = (sizeof ... (Ts) < 2) ||
    (std::is_same<head_t<Ts...>, Ts>::value && ...);

Comment: template<class ... Ts> concept all_same = (sizeof ... (Ts)<2) || (std::same_as<head_t<Ts...>, Ts> && ...);

Comment: @QuentinUK is either `same_as` and `is_same` better than the other one and how?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to specify a function parameter pack where each parameter is of the same type. The next best thing you can get (as far as I'm aware) would be a function that takes a variable number of arguments of any type as long as the type of all of them is `int`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Args>
auto f(Args... args) -> std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<Args, int> && ...)>
{
    …
}

void test()
{
    f(1, 2, 3);     // OK
    f(1, 2, 3.0f);  // error
}
```

[live example here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename...+Args%3E%0Aauto+f(Args...+args)+-%3E+std::enable_if_t%3C(std::is_same_v%3CArgs,+int%3E+%26%26+...)%3E%0A%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+test()%0A%7B%0A++++f(1,+2,+3)%3B+++++//+OK%0A++++f(1,+2,+3.0f)%3B++//+error%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

The trick here is to rely on [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to effectively remove all versions of the function where not all the `args` end up being of type `int`…

For your concrete example, you could do, e.g.:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct S
{
    int r1;
    int r2;
};

template <S& s, typename... Args>
auto f(Args... args) -> std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<Args, int> && ...)>
{
    ((s.r1 += 7 * args), ...);
}

S s;
const int mode=3, speed=1;

void test()
{
    f<s>(mode, speed);
}
```

[live demo here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Astruct+S%0A%7B%0A++++int+r1%3B%0A++++int+r2%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3CS%26+s,+typename...+Args%3E%0Aauto+f(Args...+args)+-%3E+std::enable_if_t%3C(std::is_same_v%3CArgs,+int%3E+%26%26+...)%3E%0A%7B%0A++++((s.r1+%2B%3D+7+*+args),+...)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AS+s%3B%0Aconst+int+mode%3D3,+speed%3D1%3B%0A%0Avoid+test()%0A%7B%0A++++f%3Cs%3E(mode,+speed)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Answer (score 0):

More expanded example with multiple arguments.

From this answer here > [Is there a way to define a variadic number of arguments of the same type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716940/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-variadic-number-of-arguments-of-the-same-type/67011539#67011539)

Shorter initialization (std::is_same_v) and example of using >

```cpp
template<class T, class... Types>
concept is_all_same = (... && std::is_same_v<T, Types>);

// "requires" to prevent function instance without arguments
template<class... Types> requires is_all_same<Types...>
void fun1(const Types&... types)
{
    for (const auto &t : {types...})
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

template<is_all_same<int>... Types> requires is_all_same<Types...>
void fun2(const Types&... types)
{
    for (const int &t : {types...})
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

And some usable examples

```cpp
// check same type
template<class T, class... Types>
concept is_all_same = (... && std::is_same_v<T, Types>);

// different amount of arguments, different one type
template<class... Types> requires is_all_same<Types...>
void fun1(const Types&... types)
{
    for (const auto &t : {types...})
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

// different amount of arguments one type - const char*
template<is_all_same<const char*>... Types> requires is_all_same<Types...>
void fun2(const Types&... types)
{
    for (const char *t : {types...})
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

//

// check c-array of chars
template<class T, class... Types>
concept is_c_arr_char =
    std::is_bounded_array_v<T> &&
    std::is_same_v<std::remove_all_extents_t<T>, char> &&
    (... && (
    std::is_bounded_array_v<Types> &&
    std::is_same_v<std::remove_all_extents_t<Types>, char>
    ));

// different amount of arguments
// different type based on "signature" c-array chars - const char[x]
template<class... Types> requires is_c_arr_char<Types...>
void fun3(const Types&... types)
{
    for (const char *t : {types...})
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

//

int main()
{
    fun1(1.1, 2.2);
    
    const char* a = "a1";
    const char* b = "b22";
    fun2(a, b);
    fun2((const char*)"a1", (const char*)"b22");
    
    fun3("c3", "d44");
    const char c[] = "c3";
    const char d[] = "d44";
    fun3(c, d);
}
```

And consequence at all for me - better use "init list" - there we see size() function - access to amount of arguments

```
const std::initializer_list<const char*> &args
```